# Inserting a variable to the database using sqlite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to add some data from variables into my database using sqlite library in python. I create a table and then run the sql statement. Here is my simple code:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect("dbse.sqlite")
cursor= db.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Myt (Test TEXT)")
variable = ('aaa')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Myt VALUES (?)' , variable)
db.commit()
```

but after running the code, this error comes up:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Myt VALUES (?)' , variable)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.
```

When I insert a variable that contains a one character value, it works well but when I use a variable with more than one character, it doesn't work.
I use python 3.2.3 .
Do you have an idea to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `variable` should be a tuple:

```
variable = ('aaa',) # Notice the comma
```

When creating a one-element tuple, you need to use comma at the end. As a side note, bear in mind that using the `tuple()` method won't give what you want:

```
>>> tuple('aaa')
('a', 'a', 'a')
>>> ('aaa',)
('aaa',)
```

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.execute()` expects the second argument to be a sequence. Your `variable` is a string, which happens to be a sequence of length 3:

```
>>> len(variable)
3
>>> list(variable)
['a', 'a', 'a']
```

This is what causes your confusing error message; `.execute` sees a 3-element sequency and expected only 1. Pass it to `.execute` in a one-element tuple:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Myt VALUES (?)', (variable,))
```

Note the comma there.